# Timezone conversion in ssrs expression

Tags: reporting-services, timezone

I take the UTC date from the sqlserver.
I have to display the local date and time in the report.

How to convert the utc datetime format into local datetime in the expression?
I tried this

```
=System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(Fields!DateTime.Value)
```

but doesn't work for me

Comment: "but doesn't work for me" is hopelessly vague. What happens? And is there any reason you can't just use `ToLocalTime`? (I'd strongly recommend against using `System.TimeZone` in general - it's been effectively replaced by `TimeZoneInfo`.)

Comment: Nothing happens, the time is same in the report. Time is same like in DB, UTC time. I want to see time UTC +3h fro example

Comment: Are you able to examine the `DateTime` value? If so, check what its `Kind` is - it's entirely possible that although it *is* in UTC in the database, it's coming back with a `Kind` of `Local`...

Comment: DateTime is datetime2(7) in db. I took it from the db directly. So i need some expression to convert it from UTC to mylocal timezone

Comment: That hasn't answered my question at all. Something is fetching a `System.DateTime` - I'm asking what the value of the `Kind` property of that `DateTime` is. (You also haven't said whether you've tried just calling `DateTime.ToLocalTime()` as suggested in my first comment.)

Comment: I tried DateTime.ToLocalTime() and it doesn't recognize ToLocalTime() function. And about what's the kind of DataTime, i don't understand your question. DataTime is filed took from the DB

Comment: Not `DataTime`, `DateTime`. As in [`System.DateTime.Kind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind) And I was suggesting calling `ToLocalTime()` on the `DateTime` value, e.g. `Fields!DateTime.Value.ToLocalTime()` (At a guess - I don't use SRSS; I'm inferring syntax from your post.)